# Room Temperature: Article “A” or Not?

Tags: expressions, articles, indefinite-articles

Below, “room temperature” takes the article “a” in one case but not the other. “Temperature” seems like a countable noun, so why no article in the first case? What is the grammar that is working here?

> 1. Keep the office at room temperature.
> 2. Keep the office at a room temperature of 22C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical. The first makes a generic reference, that is, *room temperature* is a noun phrase which, in the words of the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English', ‘refers to the whole class, rather than just one or more instances of the class.’

In the second sentence the prepositional phrase *of 22C* postmodifies *room temperature* and thus makes it specific. That in turn requires *room temperature* to be preceded by the indefinite article.

The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 2785 records for *room temperature*, of which 6 are for *a room temperature*. The figures for the British National Corpus are 267 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

According to Macmillan, [*room temperature*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/room-temperature) is an *uncountable* noun in its own right:

> **room temperature**, *n*.: the normal temperature inside a building that is neither too hot nor too cold

In the second sentence of your example, *room* is redundant; the sentence is better rendered as

> Keep the office at a temperature of 22C.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, the term `room temperature`, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_temperature)

> ... is a general term describing common indoor temperatures. It is usually 20 °C (68 °F or 293 K)

In the second sentence, there is no term, rather two words `room` and `temperature`, which when bought together point to the *temperature of the room*.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, '*room temperature*' is assumed as a general term, that is why there is no article.

In the second sentence, we are specifying the '*room temperature*' to a fixed value, so we need to put an article in there.

1. This river is deep.
2. This river has a depth of 20 meters.

Whenever talking about the general terms, we don't need to put an article, but when talking about a specific value, we need to put an article.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, 'room temperature' is a standard phrase taken to mean whatever the average temp. may be for the house/office, etc.
The second one simply gives more detail as to what the specific temp. is, but 'room' is not needed here because 'office' is already mentioned.